# Automation of Open Zoom

Tags: python, bash, deepzoom

How would I automate the process of deploying a gigantic jpeg on a web server and then generate the necessary files to load the image up on the frontend site in OpenZoom?

I'm working in php but any shell/bash/python scripts are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://github.com/stinie/deepzoom.php/blob/master/php5.2/tests/index.php

Using this library one can generate and display Deep Zoom Images using purely php on the fly =]